# How to pass long list of parameters to method Or any other best way to achieve this

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I am passing 20+ arguments of different types to method. There should be some clean way to pass this. Can you please help me.

I can pass array of object having all these 20+ arguments but in target method I have to put checks on type. Is this good way to pass long list of arguments.

**Code: Sample from code not full**

```
private DataTable CreateDataTable(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Clear();

    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
    dt.Columns.Add(arg);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I can pass array in this method because all arguments are of same type.

```
DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(new string[] { "ProjectId", 
                        "ParentProjectId", 
                        "ProjectName", 
                        "CreationDate");
```

Now here I have more than 20+ values of diff types like following

```
int projectId = 100;
int? parentProjectId = SomeCondition ? 10 : null;
string projectName = "Good Project"
DateTime createdDate = DateTime.Now;
.
.
.
```

In this method I would assign values to columns.

```
AssignValuesToDataTable(dt, Arguments list ......)
// Implementation would be like this. Here I am passing 20+ arguments.
private DataTable AssignValuesToDataTable(DataTable dt, arguments list ........)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ProjectId"] = projectId;
    .
    .
    .

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Can you please help. I am using `C#4`

**EDIT:**
Above code is an example from my real code but I am more interesting to know that what is best method to achieve this.

From Coding Horror (Jeff Atwood)

> The more parameters a method has, the more complex it is. Limit the
>   number of parameters you need in a given method, or use an object to
>   combine the parameters.

Above quote is from this blog post.
[Code Smells](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html)

Thanks.

Comment: re the edit... do you know what smells even worse than lots of parameters? answer: `DataTable` - just saying...

Comment: Thanks Marc Gravell, I did not know this that DataTable is that bad.

Comment: it has some uses, but as a general approach a class that describes your entity may be preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass an object that represents the data instead:

```
private DataTable AssignValuesToDataTable(DateTable dt, Project project)
{
     row["ProjectId"] = project.Id;
     row["ProjectName"] = project.Name;
     ...
}
```

with

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

of course, then the question becomes : why use `DataTable` ***at all***? since a `Project` class is a much better metaphor / mechanism for expressing that data, and `List<Project>` (or `BindingList<Project>`) is ideal for a collection of such.

(hint: I very, very, *very* rarely use `DataTable` - or maybe less frequently than that)

Comment: Thank you very much Gravell, This is very easy and good. In one answer NirMH asked about reason to use DataTable. I was using DataTable to save data in DB  [SQL Server 2008: Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) You wrote in you comments above that DataTable has some uses. I think this might be one of them. Thanks again for help.

Comment: @Muhammad as part of writing "dapper" we looked at the perf of tvp - we were very underwhelmed.

Comment: thanks for so much help. I was very exited about tvp but I have dropped that idea and going back to saving records in loop one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not constructing an object (all Public properties) to represent your data and assign values in its c-tor, then pass it to your method?

Any reason of using a datatable?

Comment: In-fact, I was trying to construct a datatable and save it in db using new DataType of 'SQL Server 2008' [See this post](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)

Comment: @muhammad: in that case, i think you should give the community some more background on your application if you want help. why do you need SQL server to achieve passing 20 or so parameters to a method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class, add the parameters as properties and then pass an instance of this class to your method

```
class Project
{
    public int projectId {get; set;}
    public int parentProjectId {get; set;}
    public string projectName {get; set;}
}
```

> AssignValuesToDataTable(Project p)

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your method to:

```
private DataTable AssignValuesToDataTable(DataTable dt, DataRow row)
{
 dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

You create the new `DataRow` ahead and asign the values to it directly from the source. Then pass along the new `DataRow` to your method to be inserted. Obviously you might want to do some checks within your method to make sure the new Row matches all constraints and conditions, before adding it.

Comment: Thanks @Bazzz, If I have to pass datarow then is there any need to create another method I can write one line over there.

Comment: true, but the reason is extandibility, in this method you can check the constraints before inserting, or do some other manipulations. Besides that you keep your Data tier seperate.